# How can I convert boolean algebra to logic gates?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, logisim

I have a very large boolean algebra equation that I designed in *Logic Friday*, but it got too complicated for it to turn into gates. Note that I am a programmer, not an electrical engineer, so please be patient.

Here is my expression:

```
Seg A = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G + A' B' C' D' E F' G + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D' E F G + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E F' G + A B C' D' E F G' + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E F' G + A B C D' E' F' G' + A B C D' E' F' G + A B C D' E' F G + A B C D E' F G';
Seg B = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E' F' G + A' B' C' D' E' F G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G + A' B' C' D' E F' G' + A' B' C' D' E F G + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E F' G' + A B C' D E' F G' + A B C D' E' F' G' + A B C D' E' F' G + A B C D' E F' G' + A B C D' E F G' + A B C D' E F G + A B C D E' F' G' + A B C D E' F' G;
Seg C = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E' F' G + A' B' C' D' E' F G + A' B' C' D' E F' G' + A' B' C' D' E F' G + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D' E F G + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F G' + A B C' D' E F' G' + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D E' F G' + A B C' D E F' G + A B C' D E F G' + A B C' D E F G + A B C D' E' F' G + A B C D' E' F G + A B C D' E F' G' + A B C D' E F' G + A B C D' E F G' + A B C D E' F' G' + A B C D E' F' G;
Seg D = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G + A' B' C' D' E F' G + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D' E' F G' + A B C' D' E' F G + A B C' D' E F' G' + A B C' D' E F' G + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E' F G' + A B C' D E F' G' + A B C' D E F G + A B C D' E' F G + A B C D' E F' G + A B C D' E F G' + A B C D' E F G + A B C D E' F' G + A B C D E' F G';
Seg E = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G' + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F G' + A B C' D' E' F G + A B C' D' E F' G' + A B C' D' E F' G + A B C' D' E F G' + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D E' F' G + A B C' D E' F G + A B C' D E F' G' + A B C' D E F' G + A B C' D E F G' + A B C' D E F G + A B C D' E' F' G' + A B C D' E' F G' + A B C D' E F' G + A B C D' E F G' + A B C D E' F' G';
Seg F = A' B' C' D' E' F' G' + A' B' C' D' E F' G' + A' B' C' D' E F' G + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F G' + A B C' D' E F' G + A B C' D' E F G' + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D E' F' G + A B C' D E' F G + A B C' D E F' G' + A B C D' E' F' G' + A B C D' E' F' G + A B C D' E F G' + A B C D' E F G + A B C D E' F' G' + A B C D E' F' G;
Seg G = A' B' C' D' E' F G' + A' B' C' D' E' F G + A' B' C' D' E F' G' + A' B' C' D' E F' G + A' B' C' D' E F G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G' + A' B' C' D E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F' G + A B C' D' E' F G' + A B C' D' E' F G + A B C' D' E F' G' + A B C' D' E F' G + A B C' D' E F G' + A B C' D' E F G + A B C' D E' F' G' + A B C' D E' F G + A B C' D E F G' + A B C' D E F G + A B C D' E' F' G' + A B C D' E' F' G + A B C D' E' F G' + A B C D' E' F G + A B C D' E F' G' + A B C D E' F' G' + A B C D E' F' G + A B C D E' F G';
```

I am attempting to create a special chip in Logisim that converts a lowercase ASCII value to a seven-segment display output.

Comment: Two words: Karnaugh map.

Comment: are the outputs really connected to the inputs? ... you show the same symbols on both sides of the equation

Comment: The seven segments are labeled A-G.  The input is A-G.  This makes confusion. Please change something.  (a-g), (A-G)  or 1-7 for segments.
https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=seven+segment+logic+circuit&docid=603500586531508642&mid=563CAA668A4ADC446465563CAA668A4ADC446465&view=detail&FORM=VIRE

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Is it just for an exercise? There are better ways of doing it for most applications.

Comment: Is there any certain reason you don't want to use an EEPROM or something for this?

Comment: it is interesing that you hve chosen not to use ascii, but to instead offset the digits by -48

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні I did use ASCII, it's just minimized.

Comment: @CassieSwett I want to build it myself. I don't want to use built-in tools. For educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window "Combinatorial Analysis". Open it via the menu "Window".

In the tab "Inputs" add all needed inputs.

In the tab "Outputs" add all needed outputs.

Edit your equations to the expected syntax. Negations have `~` as prefix, and use no semicolon at the end. AND has a higher precedence than OR, as usual. For example for `Seg_A`:

`~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ...`

Use the tab "Expression" to select one output after the other. Enter for each output separately the respective expression.

Now click "Build Circuit". The dialogue that appears gives you a few options, choose to your liking, and click "OK".

You're done.

If you want to minimize, explore the other capabilities of Logisim, and have fun!

---

Oh, I have tried this procedure to be sure. It is not hard to edit the equations, using a capable editor...

Here are the edited expressions:

```
Seg_A = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D E ~F G + A B C ~D ~E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F G + A B C ~D ~E F G + A B C D ~E F ~G
Seg_B = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + A B ~C D ~E F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F G + A B C ~D E ~F ~G + A B C ~D E F ~G + A B C ~D E F G + A B C D ~E ~F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F G
Seg_C = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C D ~E F ~G + A B ~C D E ~F G + A B ~C D E F ~G + A B ~C D E F G + A B C ~D ~E ~F G + A B C ~D ~E F G + A B C ~D E ~F ~G + A B C ~D E ~F G + A B C ~D E F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F G
Seg_D = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + A B ~C ~D ~E F G + A B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D ~E F ~G + A B ~C D E ~F ~G + A B ~C D E F G + A B C ~D ~E F G + A B C ~D E ~F G + A B C ~D E F ~G + A B C ~D E F G + A B C D ~E ~F G + A B C D ~E F ~G
Seg_E = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + A B ~C ~D ~E F G + A B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C D ~E F G + A B ~C D E ~F ~G + A B ~C D E ~F G + A B ~C D E F ~G + A B ~C D E F G + A B C ~D ~E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E F ~G + A B C ~D E ~F G + A B C ~D E F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F ~G
Seg_F = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C D ~E F G + A B ~C D E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F G + A B C ~D E F ~G + A B C ~D E F G + A B C D ~E ~F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F G
Seg_G = ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D ~E F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E ~F G + ~A ~B ~C ~D E F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + ~A ~B ~C D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E ~F G + A B ~C ~D ~E F ~G + A B ~C ~D ~E F G + A B ~C ~D E ~F ~G + A B ~C ~D E ~F G + A B ~C ~D E F ~G + A B ~C ~D E F G + A B ~C D ~E ~F ~G + A B ~C D ~E F G + A B ~C D E F ~G + A B ~C D E F G + A B C ~D ~E ~F ~G + A B C ~D ~E ~F G + A B C ~D ~E F ~G + A B C ~D ~E F G + A B C ~D E ~F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F ~G + A B C D ~E ~F G + A B C D ~E F ~G
```

This is my "main" circuit as a test driver:

[image: main circuit]

And this is the non-optimized logic:

[image]